# Change Key Positions in Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
my_hash = {
  "redis_1"=>{"group"=>"Output", "name"=>"Redis", "parameters"=>{"redis_db"=>2, "redis_password"=>"<password>"}},
  "file_1"=>{"name"=>"File", "group"=>"Output", "parameters"=>{"file"=>"/opt/var/lib/bots/file-output/ctt.txt", "hierarchical_output"=>false}}
}
```

And I would like to move the key `parameters` in each inner hash to the first position, something like this:

```
my_hash = {
  "redis_1"=>{"parameters"=>{"redis_db"=>2, "redis_password"=>"<password>"}, "group"=>"Output", "name"=>"Redis"},
  "file_1"=>{"parameters"=>{"file"=>"/opt/var/lib/bots/file-output/ctt.txt", "hierarchical_output"=>false}, "name"=>"File", "group"=>"Output"}
}
```

I have the following code:

```
my_hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  value.sort_by {|k, v| k == "parameters" ? 0 : 1}
end
```

I'm not getting any errors, but this code doesn't do anything and I'm quite lost on how to reach the output that I want.

Comment: Just curious! Why did you need to do this? Could you explain :)

Comment: I have several YAML files, and when I read them, the output that I get is the first hash that I show here in the question. And I'm using these YAMLs to configure a program, and that program needs the parameters as the first key of the hash. And I can't change the YAML files, so I needed to do this :) @PreethiKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_hash
.each {|k, v| my_hash[k] = {"parameters" => v.delete("parameters")}.merge(v)}
```

or

```
my_hash
.each_value{|v| v.replace({"parameters" => v.delete("parameters")}.merge(v))}
```

Return value:

```
{
  "redis_1"=>{"parameters"=>{"redis_db"=>2, "redis_password"=>"<password>"}, "group"=>"Output", "name"=>"Redis"},
  "file_1"=>{"parameters"=>{"file"=>"/opt/var/lib/bots/file-output/ctt.txt", "hierarchical_output"=>false}, "name"=>"File", "group"=>"Output"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's debug your code :

```
my_hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  p value.sort_by {|k, v| k == "parameters" ? 0 : 1}
end
```

It outputs :

```
[["parameters", {"redis_db"=>2, "redis_password"=>"<password>"}], ["group", "Output"], ["name", "Redis"]]
[["parameters", {"file"=>"/opt/var/lib/bots/file-output/ctt.txt", "hierarchical_output"=>false}], ["name", "File"], ["group", "Output"]]
```

It sorts the pairs correctly, but :

- it returns arrays instead of hashes
- it doesn't write the result back to the original hash

For the first problem, you could use [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h).

For the second, you could use [`transform_values!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21), available in Ruby 2.4.

Here's the working code, which is still very similar to your proposed method :

```
my_hash.transform_values! do |subhash|
  subhash.sort_by { |k, _| k == 'parameters' ? 0 : 1 }.to_h
end
```